# Change axis ranges for a ggplot based on a Predict object (rms package)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression

I am using the rms package to perform Cox regression with age as restricted cubic splines with 4 knots, see reproducible code below from the rms package documentation.
My problem is: How do I change the y axis interval for the ggplot-output? I tried adding scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20)) but it didn't alter the axis

```
library(ggplot)
library(rms)

# NOT RUN {
# Simulate data from a population model in which the log hazard
# function is linear in age and there is no age x sex interaction

n <- 1000
set.seed(731)
age <- 50 + 12*rnorm(n)
label(age) <- "Age"
sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, 
                     rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
cens <- 15*runif(n)
h <- .02*exp(.04*(age-50)+.8*(sex=='Female'))
dt <- -log(runif(n))/h
label(dt) <- 'Follow-up Time'
e <- ifelse(dt <= cens,1,0)
dt <- pmin(dt, cens)
units(dt) <- "Year"
dd <- datadist(age, sex)
options(datadist='dd')
S <- Surv(dt,e)

f <- cph(S ~ rcs(age,4) + sex, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
cox.zph(f, "rank")             # tests of PH
anova(f)
ggplot(Predict(f, age, sex, fun=exp)) + # plot age effect, 2 curves for 2 sexes
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unusually, the `Predict` class of `rms` has its own S3 method for `ggplot`, which automatically adds position scales, coordinates and geom layers. This makes it easier to plot `Predict` objects, but limits extensibility. In particular, it already sets the y limits via a `CoordCartesian`, which over-rides any y axis scales you add.

The simplest way round this is to add a new `coord_cartesian` which will over-ride the existing `Coord` object (though also generate a message).

```r
ggplot(Predict(f, age, sex, fun=exp)) + # plot age effect, 2 curves for 2 sexes
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 20))
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, 
#> which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

The alternative is to store the plot and change its coord limits, which doesn't generate a message but is a bit "hacky"

```r
p <- ggplot(Predict(f, age, sex, fun=exp))
p$coordinates$limits$y <- c(0, 20)
p
```

[image]

You can also change the y axis limits to `NULL` in the above code, which will allow your axis limits to be set using `scale_y_continuous` instead.

Comment: This solved the problem! Is there any specific reason for scale_y_continuous() not to work? Just to understand the underlying functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Although a bit laborious, you could always create the plot from first principles by converting the object to a `data.frame` first. The benefit with that way is you have full control over what you want to add.

```
age_data <- as.data.frame(Predict(f, age, sex, fun = exp))
ggplot(age_data, aes(x = age, y = yhat, colour = sex)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20))
```

[image]

@Allans approach is much simpler for your particular request though!